# Order of execution of constructors and destructors in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

i have c++ little code, with constructors and destructors.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class K { 
public: 
    K(){cout<< "3 ";} 
    ~K(){cout<< "1 ";} 
}; 
int main() 
{ 
    { 
        K a; 
        { 
            K b; 
        } 
        { 
            K c; 
        } 
    } 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**problem:**
i don't understand why answer is:**331311**

and not: **333111**.

i know that first running constructors and last destructors but inverted.

Comment: why do you have `{ K a;  { K b; } { K c; } }` the way you do ? Is there any particular reason for that? Or are you just playing around with scope ?

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. It'll help future visitors of your question.

Comment: how to mark accepted?

Answer (score 8):

Your code will be a lot easier to understand if it is aligned properly:

```
int main() 
{ 
    { 
        K a;  // a is being constructed
        { 
            K b; // b is being constructed
        } // b is being destructed
        { 
            K c; // c is being constructed
        } // c is being destructed
    } // a is being destructed

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

The general rule is, that a locally (automatically) allocated variable lives only inside its scope.

```
{
    SomeType a; // Creation
} // all local variables from matching { are destroyed
```

Comment: @AhmedMasud I'd be grateful, if you discuss changes of the contents of my post prior to its editing.

Comment: @Spook apologies, it was a minor edit around and I thought I'd just put the explanation in the explanation box for you.  You had my vote prior to the edit anyhow  you can reverse it if you like.

Comment: @AhmedMasud In this case I would agree to you, but always give the author a chance to discuss the contents of his answer. I'll leave your change, it's less confusing.

Comment: @Spook again :-) my apologies, the edit was so trivial that IMHO it didn't require a discussion, however here we are discussing it :-) so I guess that was not as time saving as I had imagined a contributory editing environment to be.